# Nginx multiple domains doesn't work

Tags: nginx, virtualhost

I have a perfect configuration which is nginx, php5-fpm, apc, varnish and mariadb. Everything works flawless except;

I am hosting a single web site, since my server resources are high and available, I want to host other web sites on the same server. When I try to add different websites into nginx the service simply does not restart.

here's my configuration file when everything works:

```
    server {
    listen  8080; 

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.domain1.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow ::1;
        deny all;
    }


location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
   expires 365d;
}

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I don't want to use seperate files for different virtual hosts, I want to do everything in default file. But when I add another virtual host like below and save default file. nginx won't restart.

```
 server {
    listen  8080; 

    root /usr/share/nginx/www;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.domain1.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow ::1;
        deny all;
    }


location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
   expires 365d;
}

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}

server {
    listen  8080; 

    root /usr/share/nginx/domain2;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name www.domain2.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location /doc/ {
        alias /usr/share/doc/;
        autoindex on;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow ::1;
        deny all;
    }


location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
   expires 365d;
}

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Please help me resolve this issue. I think something is conflicting but don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

ok I found the solution just by investigating error log.

```
2014/08/19 21:55:07 [emerg] 5927#0: could not build the server_names_hash, you should increase server_names_hash_bucket_size: 32
```

error log tells me to increase hash bucket size..

I edited nginx.conf  and set the bucket size to 32 as advised in error log, it didn't work at first, but then I set it to 64 and it worked.

just search for "bucket" in nginx.conf, uncomment it, then set to 64 (or above in some cases) it will work, unless there is another issue.

Comment: That's what error logs are for ;-). In order to help you out would be the first question I'd ask: what's in the error log.